# replace in javascript not replacing

Tags: javascript

so here is the code

```
var searchValue = "Dans-Test";

if ( searchValue.indexOf('-') >= 0 ){
searchValue.replace('-', ' ');  
console.log("reached here");
} else {
console.log("no -");
}

console.log(searchValue);
```

searchValue is still outputting Dan-Test and not Dan Test, why?

it does console log reached here so the if statement is correct

thanks

Comment: `Returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.  The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`replace` doesn't modify the original string, it's non-mutable:

```
searchValue = searchValue.replace('-', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the replace function only replace the first matched character.